# Colorbox image display not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, colorbox

I've got a simple 'a' tag in my html like so

```
<a class='gallery' href='image.jpg'>photo</a>
```

My jquery is this...

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $('a.gallery').colorbox();
 });
```

However, it just opens the image in a new window.

My imports are like so...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="colorbox.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
```

As far as the download is concerned, I extracted it into the folder with the rest of my website files.

Comment: You're including jQuery twice. Remove one of them.

Comment: In addition, what do you wish to achieve exactly, you link to an image, so it opens, which it should, or do you wish to prevent it from redirecting? In that case, add `e.preventDefault()` to your jQuery.

Comment: Okay, I removed one of the jquery includes.

Comment: What I'm expecting to accomplish is when I click the link it opens in a colorbox instead of a new window.

Comment: Seems to working: http://output.jsbin.com/xebine. Any errors in the `console`?

Comment: Ah, my console is telling me colorbox.css and colorbox-min.js are not being found.

Comment: So, here is your answer..

Comment: path always look for the path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your js ressources are not found. Try to use a CDN and check your js paths.

I put a working example here.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a.gallery').colorbox();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.colorbox/1.6.4/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
<a class='gallery' href='http://www.telegraph.co.uk/content/dam/Travel/galleries/travel/hubs/thebigpicture/the-big-picture-photography-competition-round-393/Fary-Afshar-xlarge.jpg'>photo</a>
```